# Express JS doesn't find params 404

Tags: javascript, express, post

I'm trying to write a file by passing it as a json string to an ExpressJS POST:

```
app.post('/filewrite/', (req, res) => {
  const fs = require('fs');
  console.log(req.body);
  fs.writeFile("./db/test.json", req.body, function(err) {
      if(err) {
          return console.log(err);
      }  
      console.log("The file was saved!");
  }); 
});
```

But when I'm trying to pass, it turns up a 404:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/filewrite/%7B%22db%22:[%7B%22ID%22:%2211111111%22,%22job%22:%2222222222]%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

How do I need to define the POST route to accept parameters?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not be passing the data in params but if you want to, here's how you can

```
app.post('/filewrite/:data', (req, res) => {
  const fs = require('fs');
  console.log(req.body);
  fs.writeFile("./db/test.json", req.params.data, function(err) {
      if(err) {
          return console.log(err);
      }  
      console.log("The file was saved!");
  }); 
});
```

Also you cannot write the data into a local file through server, you will have to set the static path for the folder or file, [Save post data in local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981677/using-post-data-to-write-to-local-file-with-node-js-and-express)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to appear in `req.body`, then you need to pass it in the *body* of the request, not in the URL.

Since you are trying to pass it in the URL, the route doesn't match.

I've no idea what piece of software `POST` represents, but to do this with cURL you would:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --request POST \
     --data '{"db":[{"ID":11111111,"job":22222222]}' \
     http://localhost:5000/filewrite/
```